# Run this custom css only if a specific class is available within the page HTML code

Tags: css

So, we have the following tag before the head tag. It indicates what browser it is to load specific codes that are only related to Safari Mac.

```
<html id="world-wide-air" lang="en" class="safari mac">
```

I want to apply the following CSS if the class="safari mac" is on the page. I tried the following, but that doesn't work.

```
div.spark-step-indicator__list:class(safari mac) {
margin-top: -3rem;
}
```

Comment: `html.safari.mac div.spark-step-indicator__list { … }` - select `div` elements with the class `spark-step-indicator__list`, that are _a descendant_ of an `html` element that has the classes `safari` and `mac`.

Answer (score 2):

if you put a class into html tag this class is visible into all the browsers.
So my suggestion is to remove the class from the tag and to use css media query for detecting safari.

Try to use this and put your css inside of this wrapper:

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
     @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {
          ...
     }
}
```

Pay attention there are different queries for different safari's versions.